# R utils::download.file causes data error for .txt.gz? + Recovery?

Tags: r, download, gzip, 7zip, corrupt

See the following code (Windows 10, R 3.6.3)

```
download.file(
    url = "https://www6.ohiosos.gov/ords/f?p=VOTERFTP:DOWNLOAD::FILE:NO:2:P2_PRODUCT_NUMBER:363",
    destfile = paste0("SWVF_1_22_", format(as.Date(Sys.Date()), "%Y%m%d"), ".txt.gz")
)
```

Once I try to unzip this with 7zip, this simply says "Data error."

- The funniest thing is, this code *used to work before*, going back to late Jan 2019.
- In addition, if you go to the original url, it downloads fine and it is also unzipped properly via either 7zip or WinZip.
- Downloaded files either way have the same file size, which is why I never suspected corruption of files for an entire year and more. I've tried changing `destfile` argument, as well as using `tempfile()`. Neither works.
- This style of `download.file` works fine for `zip` files. Just this `.txt.gz` files.

I have absolutely no idea what is going on, and whether my files can be recovered at all. Any advice?

Comment: Try adding `mode="wb"` to the `download.file()` call. You'll want to do that for binary data like a gz file. Otherwise "line endings" are translated to the native OS default which is not what you want for binary data.

Comment: @MrFlick Argh. Okay that works. Are you aware of any ways to recover the files already downloaded? I don't understand how it worked for a very long time, and now it doesn't.

Comment: Not safely. The bytes where changed in a way that's not easily reversible. You would need to re-download.

Comment: @MrFlick Ugh. It's not possible---the files were online for only a limited time. Would using a 010 editor or sth be a solution?

Comment: Well, what happened was that all the `\n` bytes were translated to `\r\n`. If you want to make the assumption that all `\r\n` bytes were originally `\n` then you could try that. The problem would be if there were originally `\r\n` then those would have have changed. But you would need some type of binary editor to pull that off. I guess you could read in the raw bytes in R too but that would probably be messy, mostly because again you have to guess correctly each time you see the sequence if it was changed or not.

Comment: @MrFlick thank you, that's a great place to start. No one but myself to blame for not understanding the file types in question...

Comment: @MrFlick replacing all instances seem to be working for my files in my case, thank god. You are a lifesaver!! Can't thank you enough...